# Loading a background-color for a div when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote a simple code where I'm trying to load a background-color to a div when page loads. Here is the code:

```
<div id="offerOne">
    <img src="images/images.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="img">
</div>
```

**`Javascript:`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#offerOne').attr('style', 'background-color: #f12 !important');
</script>
```

But this isn't loading background-color for div when page loads. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your code inside Dom ready,

```
$(function(){
  $('#offerOne').attr('style', 'background-color: #f12 !important');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#offerOne').css('background-color', '#f12');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="offerOne">
    <img src="images/images.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="img">
</div>
```

try

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code 
});
```